# filling web forms using QWebElements

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qwebview, qwebelement

i wanted to fill the first form on yahoo registration(https://edit.yahoo.com/registration?) automatically . 
first of all let me assure you this is for practicing with Qt Webkit only and only . no harm to yahoo or anyone else is meant by me and no harmful software will be produced .
that being said ... i know how to fill normal web forms by setting the "value" attribute to "sth"
but some of yahoo's fields are not normal . whats written inside them has nothing to do with the "value" attribute . i asked someone and was told the value is changed by js somehow .
to be exact im talking about first and second name and birth year and day fields .
so my first question is : how can i change those input fields . someone said i could evaluate javaScript which i barely know :)

```
frame->findFirstElement("#firstname").setAttribute("value","asghar");
```

my second question is about the birth month and gender and country selects . to change them i changed the element attribute "selected" to "selected" but it didnt work . when i open the select i can see my desired option is already highlighted but not actually selected . how can i select that option ?

```
frame->findFirstElement("#mm > option:nth-child(8)").setAttribute("selected","selected");
```

with many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem.
i dont know exactly why but the Qt way didnt work . 
i had to evaluate JS for the entire webform . each time getting an element by id and setting its value . it worked for me that way